# how to call value of request.session in django forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

i didnot get item list in outward forms which comes from store items database
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYFBg.jpg)

-------------------------forms.py----------------------------

```
class OutwardForm(forms.Form):    
    item = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=StoreItems.objects.none())
    quantity = forms.IntegerField()
    name = forms.CharField()
    emp_id = forms.IntegerField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.warehouse_id = kwargs.pop('warehouse_id', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.warehouse_id:
            self.fields['item'].queryset = StoreItems.objects.filter(warehouse_id=request.session['warehouse_id'])

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        # process cleaned_data as before
        return cleaned_data
```

---------------------views.py----------------------------

```
def outward(request):
    warehouse_id = request.session.get('warehouse_id')
    message = ""
    form = OutwardForm(request.POST or None, warehouse_id=warehouse_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # form = OutwardForm(request.POST)
        form.request = request
        if form.is_valid():
            item = form.cleaned_data['item']
            quantity = form.cleaned_data['quantity']
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            emp_id = form.cleaned_data['emp_id']
            opr_name = request.user.username
            if  item.quantity >= quantity:
                item.quantity -= quantity
                item.save()
                record_transaction(item, quantity, name, emp_id, 'outward', opr_name, warehouse_id)
                message = "Success"
                form = OutwardForm()
            else:
                message = "Quantity must not be less than available quantity"
    else:
        form = OutwardForm()

    context = {
        # 'items': StoreItems.objects.filter(warehouse=warehouse_id),
        'form': form,
        'message': message
    }
    return render(request,'outward.html',context)
```

-------------------------outward.html----------------------

```
      <h1>Outwoard Item</h1>
        
            {% csrf_token %}
          
            Item Name :
            {{form.item}}
          
          
            Quantity :
            {{form.quantity}}
          
          
            Name of User :
            {{form.name}}
          
          
            Employee ID :
            {{form.emp_id}}
```

Comment: You already pass `warehouse_id` to the form. But why do you don't use it? `request.session['warehouse_id']` is obsolete.

Comment: its not working outward form dosent show any item list its empty you mean self.fields['item'].queryset = StoreItems.objects.filter(warehouse_id=warehouse_id)